# C# HttpClient POST'ing Async

Tags: c#, asynchronous, httpclient

I want to send a http post that can take a couple of seconds to reply without freezing my UI, currently this code just hangs my application when the method is callled.

What am I doing wrong and how do i achieve my goal?

```
private async Task<string> DoHttpClientPost(string method, IDictionary<string, object> args = null)
    {
        {
            HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler()
            {
                AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate
            };
            handler.Proxy = null;
            HttpResponseMessage response;
            using (var myHttpClient = new HttpClient(handler))
            {
                myHttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.ExpectContinue = false;
                myHttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Charset", "ISO-8859-1,utf-8");
                myHttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(APPKEY_HEADER, CustomHeaders.GetValues(APPKEY_HEADER));
                myHttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(SESSION_TOKEN_HEADER, CustomHeaders.GetValues(SESSION_TOKEN_HEADER));
                myHttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json-rpc"));
                var call = new JsonRequest { Method = method, Id = 1, Params = args };
                var jsonObject = JsonConvert.Serialize<JsonRequest>(call);
                var content = new StringContent(jsonObject.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json-rpc");
                response = await myHttpClient.PostAsync(new Uri(EndPoint), content);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("\nCalling: " + method + " With args: " + JsonConvert.Serialize<IDictionary<string, object>>(args));
            string jsonResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            return jsonResponse;
        }
    }


    public T Invoke<T>(string method, IDictionary<string, object> args = null)
    {
        if (method == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("method");
        if (method.Length == 0)
            throw new ArgumentException(null, "method");
        var jsonString = DoHttpClientPost(method, args).Result;
        var jsonResult = JsonConvert.Deserialize<JsonResponse<T>>(jsonString);

        return jsonResult.Result;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var jsonString = DoHttpClientPost(method, args).Result;
```

This is your culprit. If you call `.Result` on a Task from the UI thread it will hang.

You'll need to async all the way up - so `Invoke` should be async and return a `Task<T>` and await the `DoHttpClientPost` call, the caller should be async etc. etc. etc.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make two changes

Modify this line from

```
response = await myHttpClient.PostAsync(new Uri(EndPoint), content);
```

to

```
response = await myHttpClient.PostAsync(new Uri(EndPoint), content).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

And looks like your intention is to wait for the post call to complete and return the results, so modify this line from

```
var jsonString = DoHttpClientPost(method, args).Result;
```

to

```
var jsonStringTask = DoHttpClientPost(method, args);
jsonStringTask.Wait(); //wait for http post call to complete.

var jsonString = jsonStringTask.Result;
```